# Netbeans comment vars

Tags: php, netbeans, documentation

How can I know about full list of comments operations for Netbeans? I saw @var @param and @return. What is the difference between /* and /** ?
How can I find tutorials about Netbeans comments variable deceleration methods?

Comment: They're comments, not "operations"; they don't do anything except document your code..

Comment: Exactly @mmyers . How can I use them for documentation of my scripts? These codes are so usefull for auto complete of functions and classes too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure NetBeans just uses phpDoc, in which case the full list is [here](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Netbeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DocumentingPhpCode), there are three documentation plugins for php. The most commonly used is phpDocumentor, which seems compatible with the tags you have already found.

Its various tags are defined [here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.pkg.html).

Comment: What is the difference between /* and /** ?

Comment: /* is a normal comment, /** is a documentation comment.